# Is Negative Look behind needed?

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to get the following text

EDIT : the second $:: / :: must be optional

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
  if { [matchclass  ::USERAGENT  contains $::XYZ ] or [matchclass  $::USERAGENT  contains $::ABC ] } { drop }
  if { [matchclass  $USERAGENT    contains ::TEST ] } { drop }
  if { [ matchclass $::useragent    contains TEST ] } { drop }
  return 
}
```

to look like this

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
  if { [matchclass  ::USERAGENT  contains XYZ ] or [matchclass  $::USERAGENT  contains ABC ] } { drop }
  if { [matchclass  $USERAGENT    contains TEST ] } { drop }
  if { [ matchclass $::useragent    contains TEST ] } { drop }
  return 
}
```

i.e remove the `$::` or `::` from the word next to the `\]`

So far I have the regex,

```
re.sub(' \$?::(?=.*\])', ' ', text)
```

However this produces,

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
  if { [matchclass   USERAGENT  contains  XYZ ] or [matchclass   USERAGENT  contains  ABC ] } { drop }
  if { [matchclass  $USERAGENT    contains  TEST ] } { drop }
  if { [ matchclass  useragent    contains  TEST ] } { drop }
  return
}
```

Any ideas ? Also what would the re method be for matching rather then replacing. search/match or findall ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the greedy dot matching pattern to a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
 \$?::(?=(?:(?!\$?::)[^\]])*\])
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It will match the `$::` only if not followed by `$::` or `::` up to the first `]`.

- `(?:(?!\$?::)[^\]])*` - zero or more sequences of (`(?:...)*`)...

  - `(?!\$?::)[^\]]` - a non-`]` character (`[^\]]`) that is not a starting point for a `$::` or `::` sequence

**Note that this regex is good to use if you are not sure of what *can* appear after the last `$::` before the first `]`.** Otherwise, a `r" \$?::(?=\w+ *])"` regex should work for you.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lM5aB2/1)

[Python code](https://ideone.com/P2WARq):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r' \$?::(?=(?:(?!\$?::)[^\]])*\])')
test_str = "when HTTP_REQUEST {\n  if { [matchclass  $::USERAGENT  contains $::XYZ ] or [matchclass  $::USERAGENT  contains $::ABC ] } { drop }\n  if { [matchclass  $USERAGENT    contains ::TEST ] } { drop }\n  if { [ matchclass $::useragent    contains $::TEST ] } { drop }\n  return \n}\n\n"
result = p.sub(" ", test_str)
print(result)
```

Comment: Your regex matches all `$::`/`::` inside the square brackets because of the greedy `.*`. You need to restrict it to match only the last `$::`. BTW, I would not use a lookbehind here since lookbehinds are much costlier than lookaheads.

Comment: Also, a lookbehind checks for known context before the string you need to match. In your case, that context is unknown (judging by your other comments).

Comment: Your answer look great, but when testing it failed to work when the second $:: / :: was missing. i.e it removed the first one instead. Question updated

Comment: That is what I assumed, the last (even if it is the only one) must be changed. Doesn't " \$?::(?=\w+ *\])" work for you? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eL1nJ3/1)

Comment: The last word can contain any character. Also I need to match it on a per block basis with the string matchclass included

Comment: Something like [`(matchclass [^\]]* )\$?::(?=[^\s\]]+ *\])`](https://regex101.com/r/eL1nJ3/4)? **Use `\1` backreference to restore the text in the resulting text.**

Comment: would this not need a negatve look behind ? as it strips off much of the text

Comment: I have updated the link above. I do not really know what you need now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100576/discussion-between-felix001-and-stribizhev).

Answer (score 2):

Since the word `contains` is (at least in your example) always before, 
you can also use:

```
re.sub('(?<=contains) *\$?::', ' ', x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex for substitution:

```
$test = re.sub((r'\$?::(?=\w+\s*\])', '', $text);
```

Lookahead `(?=\w+\s*\])` will find the `$::` or `::` from the word next to the `]`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yQ6pT7/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lookbehind as your desired matches are preceded by `contains` and make the `$` optional:

```
(?<=contains )\$?::([A-Z]+)
```

See a demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tV5wO5/2)

Comment: Your answer look great, but when testing it failed to work when the  second $:: / :: was missing. i.e it removed the first one instead. Question updated.

Comment: Which one do you mean by the *second* ?

Comment: The second $:: or ::. Also the contains can be any set of characters and the also the word that you define as [A-Z] can be any set of characters

Comment: @felix001: Then please provide additional input/output strings.